# Disabling vibration when fingerprint authentication fails

Tags: lock-screens, 7.0-nougat, vibration, fingerprint

I'm running Android Nougat 7.0 on a Wiko upulse lite phone. I would like to know whether there is a way to disable the vibration that is produced when fingerprint authentication fails. I ask because I find vibrations distracting and can read the red text saying the authentication has failed when this happens and would rather simply go with that.

Thanks.

Comment: In some phones, you can disable it when in Battery Saver mode/Power Saving Mode or in total silent mode

Comment: Another way is to root, and use an Xposed Module - Gravity Box

Comment: Yes but what if I need to be in full mode or hear phone calls alarms and notifications? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a hack that can be applied somehow? Thanks.

Comment: As of now, rooting is the best way for achieving it.